# How to center nav bar?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am building a navbar for a website and I cant get the logo and nav elements to cover the whole width of the browser. I want to the logo to float to far left and list elements to float far right.

HTML:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons-5.4.0.designerpack%20copy">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>moBurgerz</title>
    
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <header>
            <nav>
            <div class="row"> 
            <img src="Resources/img/moBurgerzLogo.png" class="logo">
                
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
            
            <div class="hero-text">
                <h1>BEST BURGERS IN <br> DA City.</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-full"href="#">I'm hungry</a>
                <a class="btn btn-empty"href="#">Show me more</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <section class="story">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Our Story</h2>
                <p>moBurgerz was established in the summer of 2017 in the DMV. Since than we have grown tremendously with the help of our customers. Every burger is made with love. Come join us and see what the hype is about.</p>
            </div>
        
        
        </section>
    
    
    </body>

</html>

css:
/*---------------------*/
/*BASIC SETUP*/
/*---------------------*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

html,body {
    font-family: 'Lato','sans-serif','arial';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    
}
section {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:  20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}


/*------------------------*/
/*Navigation*/
/*------------------------*/
header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),url("img/truck.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    
}
.logo {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.main-nav li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px; 
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:link, {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}
.main-nav li a:visited,
.main-nav li a:active, {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.story {
    color: #5d5a5a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated the code for you. I'm not entirely sure what you meant by center the navbar, but I would guess you wanted it to show in a single row with the contents aligned in the center. For that, you need to set your `.row` div to be a flex container and then align all items to the center after removing the arbitrary margins on the image and navbar items/links. Of course, you can still add them back, and the current placement will help you decide on a spacing easily.

I hope this solves your problem and answered your question. If it didn't, please let me know. Happy to help. Cheers!

```css
css:
/*---------------------*/
/*BASIC SETUP*/
/*---------------------*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

html,body {
    font-family: 'Lato','sans-serif','arial';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    
}
section {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:  20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}


/*------------------------*/
/*Navigation*/
/*------------------------*/
header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),url("img/truck.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    
}
.logo {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
.main-nav li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px; 
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:link, {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}
.main-nav li a:visited,
.main-nav li a:active, {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.story {
    color: #5d5a5a;
}

.row {
display: flex;
box-sizing: content-box;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: green;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons-5.4.0.designerpack%20copy">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>moBurgerz</title>
    
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <header>
            <nav>
            <div class="row"> 
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="logo">
              <ul class="main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
            
            <div class="hero-text">
                <h1>BEST BURGERS IN <br> DA City.</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-full"href="#">I'm hungry</a>
                <a class="btn btn-empty"href="#">Show me more</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        
        <section class="story">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Our Story</h2>
                <p>moBurgerz was established in the summer of 2017 in the DMV. Since than we have grown tremendously with the help of our customers. Every burger is made with love. Come join us and see what the hype is about.</p>
            </div>
        
        
        </section>
    
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using flexbox?

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="logoContainer"></div>
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
  </div>
</div>

.nav {
    width: "100%";
    height: 50;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;

    display: "flex";
    flex-direction: "row";
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.logoContainer {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

.itemContainer {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;

    display: "flex";
    flex-direction: "row";
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an easy way, you can put your nav items in a div, and your logo be in another div, then put both of them in a div and set:

- display: flex;
- justify-content: space-between;

for your parent div.
Just you should know to set your div(that is contain nav items) first!
As you can it is better to not use float in your code.✌